# Using variable inside command substition is being interpreted as a command

Tags: bash, shell

I'm tring to set a new variable with the piped output of another variable but it is not working. What's wrong with my syntax?

Using command substition `$()`

```
a="{\"a\": 1}"
echo $a
# output is: {a: 1} 
echo $a | jq '.a'
# output is: 1
b=$($a | jq '.a')
# error: {"a":: command not found
```

Without command substition

```
b=$a | jq '.a'
# b is empty
```

Comment: you forgot to write `echo $a` in your substitution.

Comment: @Botje argh, silly! that worked, thanks!

Comment: Also, you should double-quote your variable references (i.e. `echo "$a"` instead of just `echo $a`). [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) will point out this and many other common mistakes.

Comment: Another solution without pipe: `b=$( jq '.a' <<< "$a") `

Answer (score 0):

`jq` can process a JSON contained in a variable without using `echo` or `<<<here-string`.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

a='{"a": 1}'
echo "$a"
# output is: {a: 1} 
jq -n "$a | .a"
# output is: 1
b=$(jq -n "$a | .a")
# b=1
echo "$b"
# output is: 1
```

EDIT:

As Charles Duffy noted, it is a better practice to transmit the JSON as an argument, to prevent `jq` language directives injection from the input:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

a='{"a": 1}'
echo "$a"
# output is: {a: 1} 
jq -n --argjson a "$a" '$a | .a'
# output is: 1
b=$(jq -n --argjson a "$a" '$a | .a')
# b=1
echo "$b"
# output is: 1
```

Comment: Not particularly good practice, though -- less room for surprises if `jq -n --argjson a "$a" '$a | .a'` is used, so only actual JSON and not other JQ expressions can be present in `$a`.